# How to set the update interval of Eclipse Che?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-che

I have been working with Eclipse Che for 2 hours now. When I am coding with a colleague, the code he types appears on my screen after about 5 seconds. Is it possible to change the update interval, so I can see changes made to files immediately? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the 5 second gap is always?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, there should not be any time interval gap between two two users.
AFAIK, there is no parameter which specifies the update interval.